# AVPlayer replaceCurrentItem not reset status

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have a list of `AVPlayerItem` to play. I use a single `AVPlayer` and call `AVPlayer.replaceCurrentItem` to switch between them.

It works fine, but if one of the `AVPlayerItem` has unreachable URL, and I play it, the `AVPlayer` just broken, not usable anymore. Even if I call `replaceCurrentItem` to another item and call `play`, it still not play.

I think the `AVPlayer`'s status is set to `fail` when it tries to play unreachable content, and then I cannot use it afterward. So how can I reset the status to make it usable again?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any answers to this?

Comment: No, I end up creating 1 AVPlayer for every item and switch AVPlayer instead of switch AVPlayerItem

Comment: What I did was just before calling `AVPlayer.replaceCurrentItem`, I check for `player.status`, if is `.failed`, I will replace the AVPlayer, otherwise continue with the same player